# OpenMP: How to improve the efficiency by parallelism?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to parallel the following C++ loop using OpenMP to improve the efficiency. (The value of each element in `array2d` can be 0 or 1 or 2. The values of `array2d` are not important for efficiency so I just randomly set each value from 0, 1 and 2. The values in `count` is initialized to 0.)

```
int array2d[100][10000];
int count[3][3][3];

//omp_set_num_threads(2);
//#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    int x = array2d[10][i];
    int y = array2d[40][i];
    int z = array2d[78][I];
//#pragma omp atomic
    count[z][x][y]++;
}
```

But I cannot get improvements if I use 2, 4, or 8 threads to parallel the loop by `#pragma omp parallel for`. The execution time of the parallel versions is greater than that of the sequential version. I am curious whether this loop can be improved by OpenMP parallelism? If yes, how can I get a shorter execution time?

Comment: The number of iterations is very small as well as the work within each iteration to get any reasonable parallel speedup. Generally, you need at least some moderate amount of work to amortize the overhead related to threading (such as the creation of threads).

Comment: Moreover, atomic increments of `count` array elements can result in a significant cache contention, which makes things even worse. In your case, it is almost guaranteed, since this array is very small — it occupies only two or three cache lines. Better create a thread-local copy of `count` for each thread and _reduce_ them at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is efficiency, there are other things to do before you try OMP.

Your code is not cache-friendly: the row of 100 `int`s is 400 bytes, while the cache line is only 64. Since the values are limited to 0..2, single byte (`uint8_t`) will work better. I would even pack four of those into each byte.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 effects which can cause that your code is slower in parallel (but I do not know which one is the most impartant in your case):

1. This code is memory bound, depending on your hardware using more threads may not improve the speed of memory access, therefore the overall speed will not increase.
2. As already told by @Daniel the workload is very small, so the parallel overhead is big compared to the workload, therefore the runtime will be increased.
3. As also emphasized by @Daniel `count` array is small, it has 27 elements only. Continous increment of its elements can cause false sharing, which may reduce the efficiency significantly. You can change it by using reduction (note that in this case you do not need atomic operation, so delete that line):

`#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count[:3][:3][:3])`

If the speed will not increase, unfortunately this code is not worth parallelizing on your hardware. Try to parallelize a bigger part of your program.

Comment: Thanks Laci. I wonder how can I determine whether this code is memory bound or not, by either computing some metric or just by some simply judgement?

Comment: Profile your program (e.g. using Intel's VTune.) It will give you a large amount of information.